# Understanding addresses

Tags: blockchain, wallet, address-generation

So according to many wallets, they say you should use a different public address for every transaction for security reasons. Are all of those public addresses linked to the same wallet/private key directly or is the wallet using HD features? Also how are these addresses created in Armory for instance?

Now, saying you wanted to spend funds from the wallet, on the blockchain, will it show the same outgoing address, or are you able to spend funds from this one wallet making it look like it is coming from many different addresses?

edit: So lets say I recieve 1btc to the same armory wallet on 3 different addresses A, B, C. Are these HD or completely random addresses?

THen I want to spend 2.5 btc to my friend Dave at address D. On the blockchain, what will show up as the sending/input address? Will it be just one address (X to D), or will it show up as multiple transactions (A, B, C to D)? And also, to what address will the change come back to?

Comment: related to: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13059/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18294/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2045/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5079/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1767/5406

Comment: Please only ask about one topic when you create a question. To get good and quick answers, create separate posts that are specific enough that people understand immediately what a comprehensive answer would entail.  E.g. wallets do different things, so for which wallet do you want to know whether they use HD? How "from addresses" work is completely separate from that. Whether HD wallets are private is a third topic.

Comment: thanks for that, ive still got questions after reading through all those...and ya i get that, ill try to be more clear.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I hope this didn't sound too court. Please do ask your questions, we love to have them. Just perhaps if you could make them specific to one topic, they'd be much easier to answer and/or to link to previous questions that covered the topic already. :)

Comment: Nonono thanks for the links and suggestion....i think my edit makes the question more clear

Comment: Isn't that exactly what https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5079/5406 was asking?

Comment: yes but i dont think it was sufficiently answered

Comment: this has been answered elsewhere https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/how-can-i-choose-the-address-bitcoins-are-sent-from?rq=1 https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/bitcoin-qt-how-does-it-choose-the-address-to-take-money-from-when-sending-btcs?rq=1

Comment: also https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29962/5406